# What decides the Bit Rate on a channel/link?

Tags: routing, switch, ethernet, lan

Could someone please help me with this doubt I have regarding how the **Bit Rate is decided for a network/link because for the maximum bit rate one need to be aware of the channel/link bandwidth,right?So how does,say a MODEM/ or any transmitting device** figure out the bandwidth of the link based on which it can then fix the symbols,levels or bit rate etc.

Thank you

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general answer for a general question:

The modem (or other device) tries the highest speed it can.  If that doesn't work, it tries it's next lowest speed, and so on, until it finds a speed that works.

Comment: Thank you Ron.So I guess there is a limit on the number of levels that can be assigned to the carrier signal generated by modem for modulation,otherwise it could have crammed in any number of levels to one cycle(eg.4 levels in a cycle and assign 00,01,10,11) and make up for the bit rate without switching to the next lowest,even if the maximum allowed frequency through the link/channel is low and doesnt support a high speed.